# std::bind doesn't work with string vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to make this code compile?

```
1  #include <functional>
2  #include <vector>
3  #include <iostream>
4  using namespace std;
5  void f1(int x, int y){}
6  void f2(int x, vector<string> v) {}
7  int main ()
8  {
9      f2(2, {{"hello", "it's", "me"}});
10     auto g1 = bind(f1, placeholders::_1, 3);
11     auto g2 = bind(f2, placeholders::_1, {{"hello", "it's", "me"}});
12     return 0;
13 }
```

g1 works fine, g2 gives some complicated compile error

**EDIT:**
by popular request I give you the error:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_check_arity<void (*)(int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1439:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Bind_helper<false, void (&)(int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)>’
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1462:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = void (&)(int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >); _BoundArgs = {}]’
test.cpp:11:67:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1410:7: error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for function
       static_assert(sizeof...(_BoundArgs) == sizeof...(_Args),
       ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:11:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(void (&)(int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >), const std::_Placeholder<1>&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     auto g2 = bind(f2, placeholders::_1, {{"hello", "it's", "me"}});
                                                                   ^
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1462:5: note: candidate: typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = void (&)(int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >); _BoundArgs = {}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<void (*())(int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)>]
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1462:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1490:5: note: candidate: template<class _Result, class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bindres_helper<_Result, _Func, _BoundArgs>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1490:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:11:67: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Result’
     auto g2 = bind(f2, placeholders::_1, {{"hello", "it's", "me"}});
                                                                   ^
```

Comment: solved it, it needed ` vector<string>{{"hello", "it's", "me"}}`. just needed some stackoverflow rubberducking

Comment: When asking a question regarding a compilation error, please provide said error and the line number. It will increase the chances of someone answering. Generally you want to make it convenient as possible for someone to help you. If you solved it, please post the solution as an answer and accept it for future viewers.

Comment: It's not a string array but a vector of string, it differs a lot, pls edit title.

Comment: @titus well, you can also do `vector<string>{"hello"s, "it's"s, "me"s}` if your compiler has string literal support

Comment: @PeterT works on both clang 3.6.2 and g++ 5.2.1, with c++11 flag that is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f1(int x, int y){}
void f2(int x, vector<string> v) {}
int main ()
{
    f2(2, {{"hello", "it's", "me"}});
    auto g1 = bind(f1, placeholders::_1, 3); 
    auto g2 = bind(f2, placeholders::_1, vector<string>{{"hello", "it's", "me"}});
    return 0;
}
```